# how to play an hd video in Media Player android

Tags: android, video, media-player, playback

i have a problem when i try to play a video in format hd with class MediaPlayer in android (it gives me black display but it plays sound)... it doesn't work with hd video but it works with not hd videos... i would wanto to know what you think about this and if there is a way to fix the problem.
this is my code...

```
SingletonMedia singletonMedia = SingletonMedia.getIstance();
            final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            //String uri = singletonMedia.listaMedia.get(currentMedia).url;
            //MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.parse(uri));
            SurfaceHolder mHolder;
            SurfaceView mPreview;
            mPreview = (SurfaceView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
            //mPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mHolder = mPreview.getHolder();
            try {
                Log.w(null, singletonMedia.listaMedia.get(currentMedia).url);
                player.setDataSource(singletonMedia.listaMedia.get(currentMedia).url);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w(null, "Entrato nell'eccezione del setDataSource nel Fragment: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            player.setDisplay(mHolder);
            try {
                player.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w(null, "Entrato nell'eccezione del prepare nel Fragment: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            player.start();
```

thanks in advance for help.
is there a way to play hd videos in android?

Answer (score 0):

You should find out the encoding format of your hd video. Android os does not support too many formats.  MediaPlayer can play video with format h264 even if video is hd. If encoding foramt is h264, you should try another device.

Or you should make sure your play operation be started after SurfaceView.surfaceCreated.

Comment: You should use the tool ffprobe to check the video's video encoding format. 
Mp4 is just a container, not encoding format.

Comment: sorry, what is ffprobe?

Comment: ffprobe is a tool of video programing， you should download it. See the websit : https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html